# Fake only specific event don't work in Laravel test

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-testing

I'm using the package spatie/laravel-sluggable in my project. I need to assert that an event was dispatched. The problem is when I fake the event (`Event::fake([AdvertPublished::class])`) in the test, in theory only my Advertpublished event should be faked, but it seems the pacakge events are also faked and the method that creates the slug `generateSlugOnCreate` is never executed what results in a sql error because my slug field can't be null.

```
Event::fake([AdvertPublished::class]);

$response = $this->json('POST', '/company/adverts', ['foo' => 'bar'])
    ->assertStatus(201);

$advert = Advert::first();
Event::assertDispatched(AdvertPublished::class, function ($e) use ($advert) {
    return $e->advert->id === $advert->id;
});
```

Some one knows if I'm missing something or what can be the problem?

Comment: This looks more like an integration test than a unit test to me,  I don't normally fake events in integration testing.

Comment: The code looks right,  I've never tried to fake just one event, but it looks like you've passed it correctly after reviewing the event facade and the eventfake class.

Comment: I know, it's crazy! I'm stuck with no idea about why the Eloquent events are faking too

Comment: Are you overriding setup or anything that would prevent the app container from being refreshed from another test?

Comment: I would test this separately, I would test that such and such event was fired and in separate test just test the function `generateSlugOnCreate(..)`. And if I want to be sure even more I hit controller and assert database changes...

Comment: @Devon, I override the setUp method, but I ensure to call `parent::setUp()` to call the original method. However even if I comment my override setUp method, the things still don't work.

Comment: @Kyslik, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I'm just interested in assert that the event is fired, **but** other events are also faked, thing that shouldn't be like that beacause I'm specifying `Event::fake([AdvertPublished::class])`

Comment: I dont use fakes provided by Laravel; open up code and see what that static call does; if I need to fake an event I swap/bind/alias it in `setUp` with the fake one; same for mails and other fakes.